# ¿Cómo registrar un Activity en el archivo AndroidManisfest?

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo este código pero no funciona por qué primero debo registrar mi **activity**
en el archivo **AndroidManifest.xml**, pero no sé cómo se hace.

```
 Intent i = new Intent(this, MainSignUp.class );
       startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agrega esto dentro de tu archivo **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".MainLogin" >
                        </activity>
```

Agregalo antes de esto:

```
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Es algo sencillo.

Unicamente tienes que abrir tu AndroidManifest.xml y buscar la etiqueta

```
<application>
```

Dentro de esta etiqueta podrás ver que se declaran los activities que estas utilizando, para declarar el activity que tu quieres deberías agregar algo como lo siguiente:

```
<activity android:name=".MainSignUp"
        android:label="SignUp">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Todas las Activity que seran usadas en tu proyecto deben estar registradas dentro del archivo de [manifesto](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) `AndroidManifest.xml`, ya que una de las cosas que realiza este archivo es:

> Describe los componentes de la aplicación, como las actividades, los
>   servicios, los receptores de mensajes y los proveedores de contenido
>   que la integran. También nombra las clases que implementa cada uno de
>   los componentes y publica sus capacidades, como los mensajes Intent
>   con los que pueden funcionar. Estas declaraciones notifican al sistema
>   Android los componentes y las condiciones para el lanzamiento.

La declaración de [`<activity>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) debe estar contenida dentro de [`<application>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html)

[Aquí un ejemplo de un archivo Manifest.xml de la documentación](https://developer.android.com/samples/BasicContactables/AndroidManifest.html)

En el caso del ejemplo mencionado en tu pregunta,

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MainSignUp.class );
       startActivity(i);
```

tanto la Activity que realizaría el Intent como la que se abrira por medio de este deben estar registradas, dentro de la sección `<application>`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>     
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.basiccontactables"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sample" >

       <!-- Declaracion de Activity principal-->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Declaracion de Activity-->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainSignUp">


    </application>
</manifest>
```